# Queries on Mongo Secondary are not equally distributed

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB cluster setup with one primary and 2 Secondaries in a single shard setup. Every night we have a high load but one day and most of the read APIs have a SECONDARY_PREFERRED read preference.

But the load not balanced as shown below:
[image]

**X-Axis** -> time
**Y-Axis** -> number of queries

**Green** -> Secondary one
**Yellow** -> Secondary two

And the CPU of the corresponding machines
[image]

**X-Axis** -> time
**Y-Axis** -> % of CPU IDLE

**Green** -> Secondary one
**Yellow** -> Secondary two

We are using Mongo Java Driver
Why would the query be distributed unevenly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800618/skewed-read-load-on-mongo-replica-set/63803301#63803301

Comment: Downvote for posting graphs without axis labels.

Comment: @D.SM Updated the images and description. Please don't downvote for that reason. you could have just asked :)

Answer (score 1):

The graphs show that *load on the machines* (i.e. CPU usage) is balanced most of the time.

Drivers attempt to choose less loaded nodes as described [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst).

There is no requirement either on server side or on driver side that CPU usage on all secondaries is exactly identical at all times.

> Every night we have a high load but one day and most of the read APIs have a SECONDARY_PREFERRED read preference.

This sentence doesn't make any sense. What does night load have to do with read apis during day?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the graph and description. The machine with the most CPU utilization has received more requests to process queries. This is contradictory to the statement in the specification.

Let me know if I have to look at any metric that can help find the root cause.

Comment: What is contradictory to what exactly? You need to be very precise with what you are asking and especially with what you are *interpreting* as how various pieces that you are working with operate and what their goals are. Your post should have at least 3x amount of text it now has that explains your entire thought process.